# Add dynamic values from api to the b-progress bar VUEJS

Tags: vuejs2

I want some help in Vuejs - b progress bar.
I have some value that i get from api (for example : {{data.number}} which has 20), how can i add to the b-progress bar in vuejs to show the bar progress.
I have an example of code, but it is not working:

```
   <b-progress 
    :value="{{ data.number }}" 
    variant="success" 
    striped 
    :animated="animate"
   >
   </b-progress>
```

I am not getting the value(20) in the value field, please assist. thank you

Comment: No need to add {{}}

Comment: okay thanks @RenatoManalili. but i have tried it. it gives this error ```this.value.toFixed is not a function```

Comment: can you show the full code.

Comment: Hello Phoenix, what exactly your getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first check what you are getting in console by

```
console.log(data.number)
```

If your sure what your getting from data.number then you can simply do this:

```
<b-progress 
    :value="data.number" 
    variant="success" 
    striped 
    :animated="animate"
   >
   </b-progress>
```

you shouldn't use the mustache, rather just say data.number.